# val.replace is not a function - Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I keep getting this error every-time I execute the code below, I can't seem to figure it out

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: val.replace is not a function
>       at Object.SqlString.escape

```
var connection = new Sequelize('database', 'root', 'phase_99');

var User = connection.define('user', {title: Sequelize.STRING});
var Project = connection.define('project', {title: Sequelize.STRING});



User.hasMany(Project);
Project.belongsTo(User);

connection.sync().then(() => {
User.create({title: 'user'})
  .then(user => {
    var project = Project.create({title: 'ISD Corp'});
    user.addProject({project});
  })
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are adding product before it is created, since it is a promise do this

```
User.create({title: 'user'})
  .then(user => {
    Project.create({title: 'ISD Corp'}).then(project => {
       user.addProject({project});
    })
  })
});
```